# Use PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt to hash securely a Password-String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security, hash

I am working on a login system on my website.

How do I hash the password using an implementation in JavaScript by using a secure hashing method (like PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt)?

(I would HTTPS to transfere the hashed password to the server)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a sensible thing to do. You would have to write it in JavaScript rather than having a native implementation, so it would be desperately slow. What's the advantage to doing it client-side that you are trying to get?

Comment: I am worried about sending the password plain text to the server.. Or do you think it's enough to send it plain text to the server since the connection is secured using https and hash it on the server?

Comment: Yes, that's the way everyone does it. Hashing on the client-side is usually done as a misguided/futile attempt to mitigate for lack of HTTPS.

Comment: Do you know how to do the same in Java i.e. on the backend?

Comment: Never ever trust anything sent from the client...ever! As stated before using https to send the password to the server is fine, then use bcrypt or PBKDF2 on the server side before storing.

Comment: If you hash the password on the client side, the hash *becomes the password* and you're now storing it in plain-text.

Comment: In Java there is `SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1")` for PBKDF2.